# PHP string from HTTP post to another server

Tags: php, html, post, curl, grep

I will be using PHP further on this site, otherwise interested in learning more python to achieve these results.

I start with a search form that allows the user to enter in the 'findme' value which needs to be translated to a url. (for example purposes I will use findme = 12345678)

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="search.php" target="_blank" novalidate>
<input type="text" name="findme" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And then, I would like to retrieve a string within a HTTP post response page from a second server and store a url as a PHP string.

First I need to submit the form to another server, here is my attempt at search.php

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://another.server.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'surname' => 'surname',
    'name' => 'name',
    'findme' => 'findme'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The other server responds by serving a new page (ie. https://another.server.com/response.html), I want to then find the line containing the findme string, below is the format which the findme value of 12345678 would appear in a line of the response page. I want to save ABCDE as a string.

```
<tr class="special"><td><a href="/ABCDE">12345678</a>......
```

Hopefully I can acheive with

```
<?php
file_put_contents("response.html", file_get_contents("https://another.server.com/response.html"));
$content = file_get_contents('response.html');
preg_match('~^(.*'.$findme.'.'</a>'.*)$~',$content,$line);
echo $line[1];
$findme_url = substr("abcdef", -37, 5);
echo $findme_url
?>
```

Updated with cURL and preg_match possible solutions, however the file put contents needs to be reading the response page from cURL

Comment: Curl seems to be an option; maybe with ajax you can accomplish that too.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You're not asking to code the whole thing for you, right? Show us some code you've written.

Comment: Hi @Jack, I have some ideas for the step 1 with javascript onclick, but was leaving open to working with cURL, I will try get a demo online so my code is visible and question makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfect time to use curl.

```
$request = curl_init( 'https://another.server.com' );
curl_setopt( $request, CURLOPT_POST, true ); // use POST
$response = curl_exec( $request );

// catch errors
if( $response === false ) {
    throw new Exception( curl_error($response) );
}

curl_close( $request );

// parse response...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use this as a starting point and see how much further I can get